# Fgruler does not fit whole page after page size change

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to include a large map on my document, and I need `fgruler` to draw a ruler for me. The pages before and after the map are on A4 size paper, but the map is 10 by 15 inches. When I tried adding the map, the foreground ruler only spanned up to 8.27 by 11.69 inches on that page, instead of filling the entire 10 by 15 inches.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}

\newlength{\classpageheight} \setlength{\classpageheight}{\pdfpageheight}
\newlength{\classpagewidth} \setlength{\classpagewidth}{\pdfpagewidth}

\begin{document}
    Hello World
    \eject \pdfpagewidth=15in \pdfpageheight=10in
    \fgruler{upperleft}{0cm}{0cm}
    I'm the map
    \eject \pdfpagewidth=\classpagewidth \pdfpageheight=\classpageheight
    Hi world
\end{document}
```

I read the documentation for any clues, but haven't found anything regarding page extents. I also tried searching in Google and this site, but nothing came up.

How do I set the extent of `fgruler` after a page change, or at least let it follow the new page size?

Answer (score 1):

`\fgruler` uses the values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` to calculate the page dimensions, so you have to change those values as well:

```
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{15in} \setlength{\paperheight}{10in}
```

[image]